# The iOS Simulator is a Virtual Machine or a Emulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

The iOS simulador that installs with Xcode is a VM or a emulator like Android does?

Comment: It's not a VN or a emulator. The clue is in the name, it is a simulator. Als call to UIKit are translated to OSX and made to run in a window that resembles a iOS device.  There you just use the simulator to develop an app, you will need to test it on a real device as well.

Comment: Nice. Post as an answer so can it mark it as that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's neither a Virtual Machine nor an Emulator. It's a simulator, in another words it's a standard mac application which mimic the behaviour of iOS devices. It mimics most of the features of an actual devices, but lacks some major features. So you need to use a real device for testing some of the real world scenarios.

You can read more about simulators here : [About Simulator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH1-SW1)

I would like to quote some key information from the above linked page:

### What is Simulator

> Simulator allows you to rapidly prototype and test builds of your app
> during the development process. Installed as part of the Xcode tools,
> Simulator runs on your Mac and behaves like a standard Mac app while
> simulating an iPhone, iPad, Apple Watch, or Apple TV environment.
> Think of the simulator as a preliminary testing tool to use before
> testing your app on an actual device.

### Need of actual device for Testing

> Simulator is a useful tool, but it should not be the only way you test
> an app. Because the simulator is an app running on a Mac, it has
> access to the computer’s resources, including the CPU, memory, and
> network connection. All of these resources are likely to be faster
> than those found on a mobile device. As a result, the simulator is not
> an accurate test of an app’s performance, memory usage, and networking
> speed. For this same reason, always test the performance of your app’s
> user interface on a device. In Simulator, your app’s user interface
> may appear to run both faster and smoother than on a device.
>
> Also keep in mind that some user interface elements can be easier to
> interact with in Simulator using a mouse than when trying to interact
> with the app through touch on a device.
>
> Finally, there are some hardware and API differences in Simulator.
> These differences may affect your app when testing in Simulator.